# Reference book for primality testing

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers

im searching for good reference to understand the primality testing idea
especially the Elliptic curves and primality for stirling numbers first and second ones , so can any one suggest to me good reference ?
as i read about it from the suggestion below this test need shoof's algorithm and other two tests , can we find a short cut for this test ?

Answer (score 4):

C. Pomerance, R. Crandall. Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective

Answer (score 1):

D. Bressoud, Factorization and Primality testing.

Easy to read, but does not contain the algorithm to count the points on an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 1):

A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory by Henri Cohen. very clear and rigourous. But not sure it contains primality testing for Stirling number.